# PHP sort mutlidim array usort not working

Tags: php

Hi I need to sort an array by date:

This is my array $get:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [Date] => 02.06.2012 
        [Theme] => test 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [Date] => 03.07.2012 
        [Theme] => lol 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [Date] => 09.06.2012 
        [Theme] => hm 
    ) 
)
```

I tried following code:

```
function date_sort($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a['Date'], $b['Date']);
}

usort($get, 'date_sort');
```

But all I get is unordered dates. My date is set dd.mm.yyyy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing

```
function date_sort($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['Date']) - strtotime($b['Date']);
}
```

Comment: strtotime() in a usort callback function? that's going to be sloooooow if you've got a lot of elements to sort. Better to run through the array first and populate an extra element with the converted date; then the sort will be much quicker.

Comment: also, be careful with `strtotime()` -- it makes assumptions about whether a date is `dd mm yyyy` or `mm dd yyyy`; read the manual page and make sure your dates aren't going to be converted incorrectly.